# Generating not only unique password letters

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my password generator.

```
    var listOfCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    chars = listOfCharacters.ToCharArray();
} // RB: I've reformatted the code, but left this brace in. 
  //     I think it should be removed though... 

string password = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) // length = 64
{
    int x = random.Next(0, chars.Length); // chars.Lenght = 26 

    if (!password.Contains(chars.GetValue(x).ToString()))
        password += chars.GetValue(x);
    else
        i--;
 }

 if (length < password.Length) password = password.Substring(0, length); //stucks here at 26 because all the 26 chars from the list are used one time so there are no more chars to use, but i want to use a char more than one time

 return password;
```

My problem is: when i want to create a password with 64 chars and i use a list of chars from by example 26 he stops generating at 26 because he only takes all the 26 chars from the list just 1 time. I need in my code above a method to take 1 chars more than one so not only each char just 1 time but by example he can takes the letter "a" 3 times.

Comment: Just remove the check that the password doesn't already contain `x`...

Comment: @MatthewWatson, this should be an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has an explicit check to ensure you only use a character at most 1 times.

```
if (!password.Contains(chars.GetValue(x).ToString()))
    password += chars.GetValue(x);
else
    i--;
```

Remove this check, and you should be fine!

```
password += chars.GetValue(x);
```

**EDIT**:

Please find below the exact code you should have.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) // length = 64
{
    int x = random.Next(0, chars.Length); // chars.Lenght = 26 

    password += chars.GetValue(x);
}
```

Comment: When i removed it i have nothing at the if statement so i get a error

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your code so it adds all characters one time, and if more characters are necessary (length > 26), then it starts to add each character again. So passwords up to 26 chars have unique characters, passwords up to 52 characters have each possible characters twice, etc.

```
var listOfCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var chars = listOfCharacters.ToList();

string password = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    int x = random.Next(0, chars.Count);

    password += chars[x];

    chars.RemoveAt(x);
    if (chars.Count == 0)
        chars = listOfCharacters.ToList();
 }

 if (length < password.Length) password = password.Substring(0, length);

 return password;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only adding chars if they have not already been added to the password:

```
if (!password.Contains(chars.GetValue(x).ToString()))
```

Once all 26 chars have been added, it wont add any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string password = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    int x = random.Next(0, chars.Length);

    password += chars.GetValue(x);
}
```